# Savepoint in HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactionmanager

There are two set of Insert statements, by name A and B. If there is no exception, then both A and B is committed. If there is some exception while inserting in B, then A alone should be committed. I used HibernateTransactionManager for this purpose.

I used `rollbackToSavepoint(Object savePoint)` method available in TransactionStatus. When there is an exception in B, its not rolling back as it is stated. Its committing all the queries that are executed before the exception occurs, even though its should be rollbacked when using `rollbackToSavepoint()` method.

I'm new to Hibernate.

Comment: can you please more details of you code ?

Comment: transTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
  public Object doInTransaction(final TransactionStatus status) {
 String message = null;
 final Object savePoint=status.createSavepoint();
 try {
  //some other methods for inserting queries
 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
          status.rollbackToSavepoint(savePoint);
   LOGGER.debug("exception",e);
 }
    return true;
}
});